# Incorrect Values from counting rising edges from the B5W-LD0101 particle counter sensor

Tags: gpio, sensor

For a couple of days I've been trying to make this B5W-LD0101 particle sensor work (https://www.digikey.it/it/datasheets/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div-en_b5w-ld0101-1_2). I've connected OUT1 to GPIO23, OUT2 to GPIO22, and Vth to GPIO27. (In the code, though, I will only be testing OUT1).
This is the code:

```
from time import sleep
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

PIN = 23
VTH = 27
cntP1 = 0

def switch_callback(gpio_pin):
    global cntP1
    if gpio_pin == PIN:
        cntP1 += 1




GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)                 
GPIO.add_event_detect(PIN, GPIO.FALLING, switch_callback)           
GPIO.setup(VTH, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(VTH, 100)
p.start(10)

time.sleep(5)

def StartPulseReader():
    global cntP1
    while True:
        ftime_e = math.floor(time.time()) + 1
        while time.time() < ftime_e:
            pass
        print(cntP1)
        cntP1 = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StartPulseReader()
```

When I run it, it returns extremely high values (around 100) and the sensor doesn't seem to react if I stimulate it.
Any tips?
Kind regards.

Comment: The Pi's GPIO are 3V3.  It is not safe to use a device with 5V outputs.  What is Vth used for?  Don't use pass, use time.sleep(0.001).

Comment: Vth is the threshold voltage, I set its duty cycle at 10% at the start of the program (which I would assume is 0.33V). By changing pass to sleep there are no changes to the output.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got one of these but I've not plugged it in yet, just reading up on it first. The [datasheet](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en_b5w-ld0101-1_2.pdf) mentions:

- powered with 5V on `Vcc` (4.5 to 5.5V, desirable to have less than 30mV ripple)
- mentions `Vth` values of 0.5V but frustratingly doesn't describe its purpose - a guess would be this scales the output value (pulse count per second)
- shows block diagram with `OUT1` and `OUT2` and some 3k internal resistors to `Vcc`

For `Vth` a PWM signal with 10% duty cycle is not an analogue signal so it's going to be unpredictable/undefined as to what the device will do it you stick that down `Vth`. I would go with a potential divider on 3.3V, perhaps a 560ohm (or 1k pot set to 0.56) and 100ohm resistor pair to get ~ 0.50V out of 3.3V to match the datasheet value. If you want to vary this you could try some RC filtering of the PWM to get a fairly constant `Vth` but I'd be inclined to check that with an osciloscope with the device connected.

It looks like putting a 4.7k on each output to GND will keep the voltage in the safe 0V-3.3V range for the Raspberry Pi GPIO inputs. If you've got an oscilloscope (and a dusty room) you can check this...

Once you've got it working it might be worth comparing Pi's 5V power with having the sensor powered by some battery cells (not a power pack) to see if the stability of the Pi's 5V power affects it. I use four NiMH AA's for this sort of testing.

I suspect Figure 2 on [Omron: Development of air quality sensor for air purifier](https://www.omron.com/global/en/technology/omrontechnics/vol50/011.html) is either for the **B5W-LD0101** or similar devices. It shows that a PWM signal for threshold voltage `Vth` is going to give very strange output!

Comment: I've had the Omron B5W LD0101 running for a while now. It's written up in [Instructables: Publishing Particulate Matter Sensor Data to Adafruit IO With Maker Pi Pico and ESP-01S](https://www.instructables.com/Publishing-Particulate-Matter-Sensor-Data-to-Adafr/) including source code.